# Подскажите пожалуйста,как присвоить переменной(например "string = a") случайный символ?

Tags: c#, массивы, символы

есть ли что то вроде "Random.Next(a,b)",только для символов или текста?
Возможно это нужно сделать с помощью массива,если да то буду благодарен за пример кода

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Указывайте в тегах желаемый язык, а так да, делаете массив нужных символов и берет `arr[Random.Next(0. arr.length)]`

Answer (score 0):

Вот что я для вас придумал, функций вы можете передать любой массив и он вернёт вам рандомное значение из этого массива)

```js
var text = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'random', 'ne random', 'hz'];

function getRandomSlovo(val) {
  let max = val.length;
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  return val[random];
}

console.log(getRandomSlovo(text));
```